# Looping through axios API returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm pulling an object out of an API that I'm using to show data on a website.

Here's the object:

```
{
  "id": "25ce5d91-a262-4dcf-bb87-42b87546bcfa",
  "title": "Les Houches The Hidden Gem Of The Chamonix",
  "channel": "Cornelia Blair",
  "image": "https://i.imgur.com/yFS8EBr.jpg",
  "description": "Les Houches, located 6 kilometres from Chamonix, is a ski resort with a domain which extends from an altitude of 950 metres up to 1900 metres. Long descents through tree-lined slopes are combined with impressive views of the Mont Blanc massif and the Chamonix valley. Les Houches is twinned with the Russian villages of Sochi and Krasnaya-Polyana and was chosen by the International Olympic Committee to assist in the organization of the 2014 Winter Olympic Games. Watch for more fun facts!",
  "views": "16,950",
  "likes": "3,856",
  "duration": "4:13",
  "video": "https://project-2-api.herokuapp.com/stream",
  "timestamp": 1622991672000,
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": "7ba106bf-e74a-4c21-b59e-c485a30eea45",
      "name": "Giovana Alpine",
      "comment": "Wow! You can bet that we’ll be checking this place out when we’re in the area. The views look absolutely breathtaking. Thank you so much for sharing this with the world!",
      "likes": 0,
      "timestamp": 1623104591000
    },
    {
      "id": "921f0e8d-f9d1-44db-b4a2-a2718339891e",
      "name": "Victoire Lesage",
      "comment": "Skiing is a lifestyle! This may be hard to believe now, but I once competed here for the World Cup. The Alps are at their most beautiful when you’re shredding down them FAST.",
      "likes": 0,
      "timestamp": 1623071160000
    },
    {
      "id": "f7b9027b-e407-45fa-98f3-7d8a308ddf7c",
      "name": "Sharon Tillson",
      "comment": "Amazing footage of an amazing spot! It’s so inspiring to watch the sun rising over a landscape like this. I can only imagine how fresh the air must feel there on a snowy morning.",
      "likes": 3,
      "timestamp": 1623002522000
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm then using this data and pass it down to others components, i.e. FeaturedVideo, FeaturedVideoDescription as it can be seen in the app.js, which is working just fine.

```
function VideoPage() {
    const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);

    const { videoId } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(
                `https://project-2-api.herokuapp.com/videos/${videoId}?api_key=removed for privacy`
            )
            .then((resp) => setDetails(resp.data));
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <FeaturedVideo selectedVideo={details} />
            <FeaturedVideoDescription selectedVideo={details} />
            <div className="information">
                <div>
                    <CommentList selectedVideo={details} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

However, when I then pass it down to the component: CommentList component it stops working. It's giving me the following error "cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')". Meaning, there seems to be an issue inside the CommentList component where I'm mapping through the data.

```
function CommentList({ selectedVideo }) {
    return (
        <>
            <section className="comments">
                {selectedVideo.comments.map((comment) => {
                    return (
                        <Comment
                            name={comment.name}
                            timestamp={comment.timestamp}
                            comment={comment.comment}
                            key={uniqid()}
                        />
                    );
                })}
            </section>
        </>
    );
}
```

As it's undefined it means that it's not pulling the data from the API properly? But why is that?

I've also imported axios, useEffect and all the other things that are needed to run this code but decided to not include it in the code snippet here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{selectedVideo?.comments?.map((comment) => {
```

You got an error because before to get your data and call the setState function, it is actually undefined so you must wait until it is available and the question mark will help you.

You can also check is `details` is an empty array or not and decide to render your component or not like this:

```
if(details.length > 0) return <CommentList selectedVideo={details} />
```

Comment: It all works now as expected. I didn't even know that there was such a thing as the "?". Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

By the first render `selectedVideo.comments` is still `undefined` i.e., during initial render the `Comment` has `comment` prop with `[]`

a small e.g.

```js
const data = [];
console.log(data.some_prop.map(()=>{}))
```

so is the error ... you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) one of few ways

```js
    const data = [];
    console.log(data?.some_prop?.map(()=>{}))
```

as  `selectedVideo?.comments?.map()...` - no error here because it returns `undefined` as soon as the property doesn't exist as mentioned in docs link shared above.

after the first render, the component function gets called with new data, in which you have the data set earlier using `setDetails` ..

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense then because during the initial render it's undefined and then stops the code. Meaning, the second render won't even get executed which would contain all the data.

Comment: React component is just a javascript function so, during first render the react calls the function with initial state ,then you set the data which causes a re-render which is react calls the function with new values ignoring initial state .... Then you have the data in this render .. hope it's clear 